# how to exclude a particular folder in grunt build.

Tags: batch-file, gruntjs

I made a separate task for grunt build & after that i am creating zip package for AEM CQ. There are so many images so i would like to exclude images folder so that it will take less time.

**My Build BAT files like :**

```
grunt build:cq --appName=%tenant%> packageMapper.log 2>&1 && exit  

java -jar Package_mapper_utility\packagemapper.jar %buildNum% local %tenant% %uiGruntLoc% %outputFolderLoc% %AEMdependencies% >> packageMapper.log 2>&1
```

Comment: This does not seem to me like a batch-file problem.  Wouldn't that functionality have to be within your JAVA program?

Comment: Yes but firstly it runs first command than it creates a zip file, so if i exclude images in build folder then it will not be zipped.